# When executing a script on SQLPlus, it prints a sequence of numbers instead of output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to execute a script on SQL PLus, it's simple.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
    mode NUMBER(1) := 1;

IF (mode = 1) THEN

    prompt 'HERE'

END IF;

prompt 'fim'
```

I call the script from SQLPlus using `sqlplus user/pw@db` and `@myscript.sql` after a successful connection. But the output is strange for me:

```
Conectado a:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

SQL> @myscript.sql
 9
 10
 11
```

And it continues to print this sequence indefinitely.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Definitely you get `here` printed and nothing else unless you have something else in your script.

Comment: What do you have in your script.sql?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar just this prompt. nothing else.

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe tried now. same output

Comment: `SQL> !cat myscript.sql
prompt 'here'

SQL> @myscript.sql
'here'
`

Comment: I get 'here' printed..!! I use oracle 11g, can u do a cat, I believe there's something else in your sql file!

Comment: It prints code's line number, and it probably prints it when you hit enter.  The reason for such a behavior is probably your `myscript.sql` file contains not terminated by `/` PL/SQL block.

Comment: I don't think you're executing the script you think you are. (It does look like it contains a PL/SQL block without a termination). Is it in the same directory you launched SQL*Plus from? Do you have [`SQLPATH` set in your environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#sthref64)?

Comment: Worked now. I think I was executing the wrong script. I'll make a edit because I'm facing the same problem with other script.

Comment: till u give a `'/'`, your script contents as PL/SQL block will be never sent to oracle, and it waits showing number starting from last line number of ur script as you keep pressing Enter!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From your edited question... you have to terminate the PL/SQL block with a `/` on a new line to make it end and run, otherwise SQL*Plus will keep prompting for more lines of code (which is the numbers you're seeing). [The documentation shows how to run PL/SQL blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663). And `prompt` is a SQL*Plus command so you can't use it inside a PL/SQL block. You also don't have your block syntax right:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
    mode NUMBER(1) := 1;
BEGIN
    IF mode = 1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HERE');    
    END IF;
END;
/

prompt fim
```

Comment: @DiogoMoreira - please read the documentation to make sure you understand why it works now, and why your version didn't work. As well as the SQL*Plus guide, you should look the [PL/SQL language reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use sqlplus command in plsql.We can use dbms_output instead which will display the output in SQL prompt

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
mode NUMBER(1) := 1;
BEGIN
IF (mode = 1) THEN
dbms_output.put_line('HERE');
END IF;
dbms_output.put_line('fim');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your oracle home `Oracle\product\<version>\client_2\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql` and add the following lines to enable printing globally,

```
SET ECHO ON;
SET TERM ON;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
SET DEFINE OFF;
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the actual problem; your answer will show what is being executed, but the comments to the original post answer the question.