# PL/SQL Trigger Issues

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger to populate a table containing information on an employee's updated salary. I'm having a problem that I can't quite wrap my head around at the moment.

Here is the table to be populated:

```
 drop table SalUpdates cascade constraints;
 create table SalUpdates(
 SalSSN char(9), 
 newSalary decimal(10,2), 
 oldSalary decimal(10,2)

 );
```

This is my trigger:

```
 create or replace trigger t1
 after update of salary on employee
 for each row
 begin
 insert into SalUpdates values (:old.Ssn, :new.salary, :old.salary);  
 end;
```

The trigger compiles with no issues, but when I try to run this update, Oracle tells me my trigger is invalid. What could be causing this?

```
update employee
set salary=4000
where ssn='123456789';
```

Comment: Seems fine. Are you sure the error message refers to `T1` - you haven't tried to create the trigger before with a different name? You can query the `user_errors` view to see what is wrong though. If that doesn't make it clear for you, add the relevant errors from that to your question.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are dropping the `SalUpdates` after you have created the trigger?

Comment: When I run my entire script, I get no problems with the trigger, but now I'm getting the error "Encountered the symbol update" Why is that?

Comment: @Plirkee I don't believe so

Comment: Right, looks like you're just missing a `/` on a blank line between the `end;` and `update`, perhaps?

Comment: I think that may have worked! I have one more thing to check, but thank you! I'm still relatively new to using PL/SQL so there are small syntactical things I forget from time to time

Comment: Yup that did the trick. So newbie question, is that always a rule of thumb to put a forward slash in btwn a procedure/function/trigger and a regular sql query?

Comment: If you'd like alex you can copy that into an answer so I can upvote you for it. I really appreciate it. I was pulling my hair out over this haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've shown the code in chunks. but it seems you're running what you've shown together as a script, initially without the update:

```
drop table SalUpdates cascade constraints;
create table SalUpdates(
SalSSN char(9), 
newSalary decimal(10,2), 
oldSalary decimal(10,2)
);

create or replace trigger t1
after update of salary on employee
for each row
begin
insert into SalUpdates values (:old.Ssn, :new.salary, :old.salary);  
end;
```

When run as a script in SQL Developer the script output window shows:

```
drop table SalUpdates cascade constraints
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Table SALUPDATES created.


Trigger T1 compiled
```

If you then add the update statement to the script:

```
drop table SalUpdates cascade constraints;
create table SalUpdates(
SalSSN char(9), 
newSalary decimal(10,2), 
oldSalary decimal(10,2)
);

create or replace trigger t1
after update of salary on employee
for each row
begin
insert into SalUpdates values (:old.Ssn, :new.salary, :old.salary);  
end;

update employee
set salary=4000
where ssn='123456789';
```

you get:

```
Table SALUPDATES dropped.


Table SALUPDATES created.


Trigger T1 compiled

Errors: check compiler log
```

If you then try to run the update on it's own (as a statement instead of a script; or by selecting that test and running as a script) you do indeed get:

```
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'MYSCHEMA.T1' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

If you query the `user_errors` view, or run `show errors`, you'll see:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE"
```

The problem is that you aren't completing the `create trigger` statement properly. The `update` is being seen as part of the same PL/SQL block; an invalid part, but still included.

When you have a PL/SQL block you have to terminate it with a slash, [as it explains in the SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663) (which mostly applies to SQL Developer too):

> SQL*Plus treats PL/SQL subprograms in the same manner as SQL commands, except that a semicolon (;) or a blank line does not terminate and execute a block. Terminate PL/SQL subprograms by entering a period (.) by itself on a new line. You can also terminate and execute a PL/SQL subprogram by entering a slash (/) by itself on a new line.

SQL Developer doesn't complain if the last block in a script doesn't have a terminating slash though, so your original script (without the update) works; [in SQL*Plus it would sit at a prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20971731/266304). It kind of infers that it should be there - trying to be helpful. When you add the `update` statement it is no longer the end of the script so that doesn't apply.

If you add a slash to your script between the PL/SQL code and the following SQL statement it all works:

```
drop table SalUpdates cascade constraints;
create table SalUpdates(
SalSSN char(9), 
newSalary decimal(10,2), 
oldSalary decimal(10,2)
);

create or replace trigger t1
after update of salary on employee
for each row
begin
insert into SalUpdates values (:old.Ssn, :new.salary, :old.salary);  
end;
/

update employee
set salary=4000
where ssn='123456789';
```

and you now see:

```
Table SALUPDATES dropped.


Table SALUPDATES created.


Trigger T1 compiled


1 row updated.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very informative and answered every question I had. I really appreciate it