# Oracle SQL automatically create VARCHAR incremented PK

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write an Oracle SQL table such that whenever a row is inserted (through an Oracle APEX form), the PK is automatically populated with a varchar type that automatically increments. Eg. TNT00000001, TNT00000002, TNT00000003...

```
 create table sample (
Tnt_ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
wtv NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE Tnt_ID_Auto 
 MINVALUE 1  START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1  CACHE 10;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sample_on_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON sample
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT('TNT', LPAD(Tnt_ID_Auto.nextval, 5, '0'))
  INTO :new.Tnt_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
```

When I try to run this:

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (wtv) VALUES (1);
```

I get the error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Comment: `LPAD(Tnt_ID_Auto.nextval, 5, '0')` won't give you the requisite number of zeros for `TNT00000001` btw

Comment: Dare say you can simplify the trigger to just `:new.Tnt_ID := CONCAT('TNT', LPAD(Tnt_ID_Auto.nextval, 8, '0'));` too

Comment: What is above the INSERT in your script?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. The code before the insert statement was the stuff from create table to end

Comment: Oracle is complaining that it encountered insert when it was expecting something else. Run an insert in a fresh empty script with nothing above it (I think you missed a delimiter in your original script) or your query tool didn't separate the queries properly before sending them to oracle

Comment: Basically [the same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43479838/266304) - missing a slash.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for **IDENTITY** and **VIRTUAL** columns. So, no need of an additional **SEQUENCE** and **TRIGGER**.

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
    serial_no NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    tnt_id GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('TNT', LPAD(serial_no, 5, '0'))) VIRTUAL,
    wtv    NUMBER(3)
);

insert into sample (wtv) values(100);
insert into sample (wtv) values(200);
insert into sample (wtv) values(300);
```

Result:

```
select * from sample;

 SERIAL_NO TNT_ID                         WTV
---------- ----------------------- ----------
         1 TNT00001                       100
         2 TNT00002                       200
         3 TNT00003                       300
```

How it works:

1. `NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`: This automatically creates the required sequence for you, starts with 1 and increments  by 1 by default.
2. `GENERATED ALWAYS AS VIRTUAL`: This creates a virtual column whose values are calculated automatically using other column values. In this demo it uses the identity column.
3. `LPAD`: This will ensure zeroes are left padded while the column value is incremented, but will also ensure that when the number is incremented it doesn't increase the length of the string.
4. `CONCAT`: This will concat `TNT` to above value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is wrong with your queries, It is missing `/`

```
create table sample (
Tnt_ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
wtv NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE Tnt_ID_Auto 
 MINVALUE 1  START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1  CACHE 10;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sample_on_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON sample
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT('TNT', LPAD(Tnt_ID_Auto.nextval, 5, '0'))
  INTO :new.Tnt_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
/ -- this needs here

INSERT INTO SAMPLE (wtv) VALUES (1);
```

PL/SQL code must be ended with the `/` before starting another code below it.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I had an error like this: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Comment: @Alioz - it has to be a slash on its own it some clients (SQL Developer will throw PLS-00103; SQL\*Plus thinks the statement hasn't ended...) so remove the comment "-- this needs here" if you included that verbatim.

Comment: Avoid triggers unless it's the last resort.