# SQL Insert statement - issue with incrementing userID

Tags: oracle

I have `userID` in the table like `USR1`,`USR2`.
When I am trying to insert a new value ,I want to increment the userID to `USR3`. Please help in doing the same

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( userid ) VALUES ( MAX(userid) + 1 )
```

is not working

Comment: Well ... don't. Use a sequence instead. Your approach will work in a single-user environment and will (sooner or later) fail in multi-user environment as two (or more) users will fetch the same MAX value and you'll get duplicates. I presume you don't want them. There is a way to do it; create a function which will determine the next value in autonomous transaction based on a separate table (that contains the last ID value) which will lock the table until next value is being computed. If I remember well, I posted such an example already. Not too complex, but *why*? Sequences are just fine.

Comment: Or, if your database version supports it, create virtual column. See Lalit's demonstration, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012534/oracle-sql-automatically-create-varchar-incremented-pk/61013720#61013720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Littlefoot's comment is spot on.

But if you want to go with the way you are currently using (**not recommended**), try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( userid ) VALUES ( MAX(to_number(substr(userid, 4, length(userid)))) + 1 );
```