# ORACLE - How do I run a begin/end command in sqlplus command line

Tags: oracle

I'm following an APEX tutorial for beginners, but it does not explains a lot of things, so I have no clue about what I'm doing wrong.

I need to run this command on a sysdba command line :

```
BEGIN
APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.REMOVE_WORKSPACE(DEV_WORKSPACE, y, y)
END;
```

But it refuses to run. Each time I press the enter key, it creates a new numerated line.

How do I finish entering the command? It will run automatically, or I need to call it?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql), in particular the most voted answer.

Comment: [Have a look at this too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20971731/266304).

Comment: Thank you gile, aleksej and Poole. Oracle guides are chaotic. They assume that the reader knows everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a slash at the end of the command.

```
BEGIN
APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.REMOVE_WORKSPACE('DEV_WORKSPACE', 'y', 'y');
END;
/
```

Comment: @xihocipi - the statement inside the block needs a semicolon at the end as well.

Comment: ¿should finish the second line with ";" ??

Comment: Yes. @Alex Poole corrected the statement in the answer (thanks).

Comment: Oh, I see. It is like c. Each line ends with a semicolon.

Comment: @xihocipi - the `y` values should be in single quotes too, to make them string literals - `...(DEV_WORKSPACE, 'Y', 'Y');`. [The docs are here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_instance.htm#AEAPI252).